# Unable to fetch data from Hashmap properly

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, android-listview

I have an `Arraylist` of `HashMap`. Each `HashMap` element contains two columns: column name and corresponding value. This `HashMap` will be added into a `ListView` with 3 `TextView`.

I populate the `ArrayList` as follows, and then assign that to an adapter in order to display it:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> addList1;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

addList1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
addList1.put(COLUMN1, symbol[i]);
addList1.put(COLUMN2, current[i]);
addList1.put(COLUMN3, change[i]);

list1.add(addList1);

RecentAdapter adapter1 = new RecentAdapter(CompanyView.this,
                    CompanyView.this, list1);
listrecent.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }
```

.

Now on `listItemClick`, the fetched data is of the **different form at different time**.

For eg. My list contains following data:

```
ABC  123  1
PQR  456  4
XYZ  789  7
```

i.e. When I log the fetched string after clicking 1st list item, I get one of the several outputs:

*{1=ABC ,2=123 ,3=1}*

*{First=ABC ,Second=123 ,Third=1}*

*{1=123 ,0=ABC ,2=1}*

and even 
*{27=123 ,28=1 ,26=ABC}*

Initially I used:

```
int pos1 = item.indexOf("1=");
int pos2 = item.indexOf("2=");
int pos3 = item.indexOf("3=");

String symbol = item.substring(pos1 + 2,pos1 - 2).trim();
String current = item.substring(pos2 + 2, pos3 - 2).trim();
String change = item.substring(pos3 + 2, item.length() - 1).trim();
```

Then for the 4th case, I have to use:

```
int pos1 = item.indexOf("26=");
int pos2 = item.indexOf("27=");
int pos3 = item.indexOf("28=");

String symbol = item.substring(pos1 + 3, item.length() - 1).trim();
String current = item.substring(pos2 + 3, pos3 - 3).trim();
String change = item.substring(pos3 + 3, pos1 - 3).trim();
```

So that I get `ABC` in `symbol` and so on.

But, by this approach, application **loses it's reliability** completely.

I also tried

```
while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {

key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
value[ind] = (String) addList1.get(key);
                }
```

But it's not giving proper value. Instead it returns random symbol for eg. ABC or PQR or XYZ.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HashMap's put function does not insert value in specific order. So the best way is to put the keyset of the HashMap in a ArrayList and use the ArrayList index in retrieving the value

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> addList1;
ArrayList<String> listKeySet;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

addList1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
addList1.put(COLUMN1, symbol[i]);
addList1.put(COLUMN2, current[i]);
addList1.put(COLUMN3, change[i]);

listKeySet.add(COLUMN1);
listKeySet.add(COLUMN2);
listKeySet.add(COLUMN3);

list1.add(addList1);

RecentAdapter adapter1 = new RecentAdapter(CompanyView.this,
                CompanyView.this, list1);
listrecent.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
```

And when retrieving use

```
addList1.get(listKeySet.get(position));
```

Here, the arraylist listKeySet is just used to preserve the order in which the HashMap keys are inserted. When you put data in HashMap insert the key into the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `HashMap` for this purpose is a good idea. I would implement Class incapsulating your data like

```
class myData {
    public String Column1;
    public String Column2;
    public String Column3;
    // better idea would be making these fields private and using 
    // getters/setters, but just for the sake of example these fields
    // are left public

    public myData(String col1, String col2, String col3){
        Column1 = col1;
        Column2 = col2;
        Column3 = col3;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
ArrayList<myData> list1 = new ArrayList<myData>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    list1.add(new myData(symbol[i], current[i], change[i]));
}
//no need to create new adapter on each iteration, btw
RecentAdapter adapter1 = new RecentAdapter(CompanyView.this,
                CompanyView.this, list1);
listrecent.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

You will need to make changes in your adapter to use myData instead of `HashMap<String,String>`, of course.